# Proof with Error, if a|b and b|c then a|c since b =ak and c=bk so c=bk=(ak)k=ak^2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility, fake-proofs

Having trouble figuring out the issue with the question in my textbook

*Here is a sample proof that contains an error. Explain why the proof is not correct.*

Theorem: If a\b and b\c, then a\c.

Proof: Since a|b, b = a*k.

Since b|c, c = b*k.

Therefore c = b*k = (ak)k = a*k*k = a(k^2)

Therefore a|c

From my understanding (ak)k = ak^2 checks out and properties of divisibility rules state that a|b means that b is some multiple of a. Is the issue with the proof that there is no "assumption" being made at the start or some kind of notation error?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your argument is basically fine, it's just that you need two different factors, $k_1,k_2$, instead of the single $k$.  There is, of course, no reason why the same factor $k$ should work for both $a$ and $b$ (unless $a=b$, it won't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The error lies in the fact that the number $k$ such that $b=a\times k$ doesn't have to be such that $c=b\times k$. From the fact that $b\mid c$, what follows is that $c=b\times k'$ for some integer $k'$ (which doesn't have to be $k$). Therefore $c=a\times(k\times k')$. It follows that $a\mid c$.

Comment: thank you for the quick response, this makes sense now!